# VPN Connected but url not not open

Tags: linux, vpn

I have use CentOS 7 system and developing a SOAP web service. I connected FortiClient CLI  using the terminal to the VPN server that is hosted on a windows server and it's working perfectly.

But Shared WSDL URL is not opening on my CentOS system when I use windows  system its open the WSDL URL.

Does it need to be configured on the windows server or is it my systems fault?

Comment: I tried to make more understandable English from your post. Please review if I did not interpret things incorrectly (and roll-back if necessary).